# CSS Zoom property not working (Jquery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, zooming

Im Using the zoom property in JQuery to zoom my body.
 So far, this only works in Google Chrome, Not in IE. Using IE 11.
This is what i have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('body').css("zoom", "70%");
});
```

Wich works perfectly in Chrome. For some reason i can't get this to work in IE.
Anyone who has a solution to this IE problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. for MS

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $('body').css("-ms-zoom", "70%");
});
```